# Not able to add configurable products into wishlist with color value

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

For **add to wishlist** anchor button, I have used the following code on my product details phtml file.

```
<?php if ($block->isWishListAllowed()) : ?>
<a href="#"
class="action towishlist"
data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getWishlistParams() ?>'
data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')) ?></span></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
"body": {
"addToWishlist": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getWishlistOptionsJson() ?>
}
}
</script>
```

But when I click the att to wishlist link, it added the product into the wishlist without color option and when I try to add to cart from the wishlist section it shows me below error.

[image]